# pytest - how to assert if a method of a class is called inside a method

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to figure out how to know if a method of class is being called inside a method.

following is the code for the unit test:

```py
# test_unittes.py file

def test_purge_s3_files(mocker):
    args = Args()
    

    mock_s3fs = mocker.patch('s3fs.S3FileSystem')
    segment_obj = segments.Segmentation()
    segment_obj.purge_s3_files('sample')

    mock_s3fs.bulk_delete.assert_called()
```

inside the `purge_s3_file` method `bulk_delete` is called but when asserting it says that the method was expected to be called and it is not called!

```sh
mocker = <pytest_mock.plugin.MockerFixture object at 0x7fac28d57208>

    def test_purge_s3_files(mocker):
        args = Args()
    
        mock_s3fs = mocker.patch('s3fs.S3FileSystem')
        segment_obj = segments.Segmentation(environment='qa',
                        verbose=True,
                        args=args)
        segment_obj.purge_s3_files('sample')
    
>       mock_s3fs.bulk_delete.assert_called()
E       AssertionError: Expected 'bulk_delete' to have been called.
```

I don't know how to test this and how to assert if the method is called!

---

Below you can find the method being testing:

```py
# segments.py file

import s3fs

def purge_s3_files(self, prefix=None):
    bucket = 'sample_bucket'
    files = []
    fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
   
    if fs.exists(f'{bucket}/{prefix}'):
        files.extend(fs.ls(f'{bucket}/{prefix}'))
    else:
        print(f'Directory {bucket}/{prefix} does not exist in s3.')
    
    print(f'Purging S3 files from {bucket}/{prefix}.')
    print(*files, sep='\n')
    fs.bulk_delete(files)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is under test, or at least some contextual representation around the code in question? That would help provide more context around what could be going wrong.

Comment: Check if the mock is correct. Is the module path correct in the mock setup

Comment: @idjaw I've added more info and context

Comment: @leoOrion how should I do this? all to setup the mock is in the code here

Comment: This `purge_s3_files` is in which file. I am assuming you would import s3fs in that file. Its that import that should be mocked. If its in a file with path `a.s3`. Then the mock should be as `mocker.patch('a.s3.s3fs.S3FileSystem')`

Comment: I added file names and a little more context. so you are saying I should mock `segments.s3fs.S3FileSystem' ? @leoOrion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that the mock you are setting up is mocking out the class, and you are not using the *instance* to use and check your mocks. In short, this *should* fix your problem (there might be another issue explained further below):

```
m = mocker.patch('s3fs.S3FileSystem')
mock_s3fs = m.return_value  # (or mock_s3())
```

There *might* be a second problem in how you are not referencing the right *path* to what you want to mock.

Depending on what your project root is considered (considering your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70285003/pytest-how-to-assert-if-a-method-of-a-class-is-called-inside-a-method?noredirect=1#comment124245243_70285287)) your mock would need to be referenced accordingly:

```
mock('app.segments.s3fs.S3FileSystem')
```

The rule of thumb is that you always want to [mock where you are testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

If you are able to use your debugger (or output to your console) you will (hopefully :)) see that your expected call count will be inside the `return_value` of your mock object. Here is a snippet from my debugger using your code:

[image]

You will see the `call_count` attribute set to `1`. Pointing back to what I mentioned at the beginning of the answer, by making that change, you will now be able to use the intended `mock_s3fs.bulk_delete_assert_called()`.

Putting it together, your working test with modification runs as expected (note, you should also set up the expected behaviour and assert the other `fs` methods you are calling in there):

```
def test_purge_s3_files(mocker):
    m = mocker.patch("app.segments.s3fs.S3FileSystem")
    mock_s3fs = m.return_value  # (or m())

    segment_obj = segments.Segmentation(environment='qa',
                    verbose=True,
                    args=args)
    segment_obj.purge_s3_files('sample')
    
    mock_s3fs.bulk_delete.assert_called()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python mock testing depends on where the mock is being used. So you have the mock the function calls where it is imported.

Eg.

**app/r_executor.py**

```
def r_execute(file):
  # do something
```

But the actual function call happens in another namespace ->

**analyse/news.py**

```
from app.r_executor import r_execute

def analyse():
  r_execute(file)
```

To mock this I should use

```
mocker.patch('analyse.news.r_execute')
# not mocker.patch('app.r_executor.r_execute')
```

Comment: s3fs is a package I am using inside my python application, so it is not written by me! or you are referring to something I cannot understand!

Comment: it doesnt matter where s3fs is. Mock it where you import it.

Comment: so my python script located in `c:\app\segments.py` and my test is located in `c:\app\test\ test_unittes.py`,  you are saying that I should mock like this: `mock('segments.s3fs.S3FileSystem')`?

Comment: `app.segments.s3fs.S3FileSystem`